# Confuse about Queue + Random numbers

Tags: java, random, queue

So basically I have this email simulation thingy, so the email needs to be dequeue from queue in order to be able to send them to the receiver.

The question says:
"Each minute, you can dequeue up to 40 messages and send them. Assume that 25% of the messages in the queue cannot be sent in any processing cycle. Again, you will need to use a random number to determine whether a given message can be sent. If it cannot be sent, put it back at the end of the queue or enqueue it."

How can I get the 25% of 40 message and determine whether a message can be sent or not (randomly). I don't get the logic. Is there master here to help me finishing this in java?

Thanks heaps.
*please use a basic language of programming. I am very bad at this programming language. thanks

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. What have you tried so far, any code?

Comment: I have done the enqueue-ing part. and now i have to do the dequeueing part. However, I don't get the logic of how to do it with 25% of the 40 message with the random thingy. Any explanation about how to do this would be great.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void sendMessage(Message m) throws MessageCantBeSentException {
    if (random.nextDouble() < 0.25) {
        throw new MessageCantBeSentException("Bad luck!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm actually it has to be 40 (fixed size of email). and there is a 25%(10 email) of the total email can't be sent. how to determine which email can be sent and which ones can't ?

Comment: The assignment tells you to use a random number so that [on average], 25% of the messages can't be sent. That's what the above does. Of course, it doesn't say [on average], but it's a simulation, so the goal is simply to have failures and successes. You don't need *exactly* 10 messages to fail. Ask your teacher if you're not sure, but I guess that's what he meant.